# Debug and list all coroutine pending by future in python asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, semaphore, python-asyncio, ipdb

I have a production code that heavily used asyncio.semaphore module which is suspected to have deadlock problem.
I already found some solution of how to attach to running python code with unix signal, debug with `ipdb.set_trace()` and list all tasks on event loop with `asyncio.Task.all_tasks()`. Can I further inspect into the stack frame of each task or viewing each line of coroutine which is currently pending by futures on `ipdb`?

Comment: Every task has method `Task.get_stack()`. Maybe this is what you looking for.

Comment: @Qeek Thanks for idea. ```[*map(asyncio.Task.print_stack, asyncio.Task.all_tasks())]``` works fine.

Comment: just for info.

In python 3.7 you can use `asyncio.all_tasks()` instead of `asyncio.Task.all_tasks()`

`asyncio.Task.all_tasks()` is deprecated and will be removed in python 3.9

Answer (score 3):

As OP observes, further inspections may be obtained with

```
[*map(asyncio.Task.print_stack, asyncio.Task.all_tasks())]
```

(OP is certainly free to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).)

Comment: I have a lot of tasks, all created by the same code, but with different data. I'd like to see which one is the bad one that's still running when my app exits; the stack isn't very helpful to me. Is there any way to give a task a name that will be printed out by str(task) or repr(task)?

Comment: Well, if you define a class that inherits from Task, then you could certainly add an attribute and override repr so it displays that attribute.